# Variable 'name' doesn't return undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, hoisting

I'm learning about hoisting in JavaScript. When I try this code

```
console.log('name', name)
console.log('age', age)
console.log('occupation', occupation)

var name = 'tom'
var age = '23'
var occupation = 'builder'
```

in my developer tools in chrome i get

```
name tom
age undefined
occupation undefined
```

how come name is not undefined but other variables are?

Edit:

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js file

```
console.log('name', name)
console.log('age', age)
console.log('occupation', occupation)

var name = 'tom'
var age = '23'
var occupation = 'builder'
```

I restarted my computer, created new files and nothing has changed. 
In firefox I get

```
name <empty string> 
age undefined 
occupation undefined
```

Comment: this is strange, `name` should also not be defined imho

Comment: Can you share all your code? I'm assuming there is more of it because `name` should also be `undefined`

Comment: That is all, my whole code, I restarted my computer, created a new project and nothing has changed.

Comment: `var something = somethingelse` in global scope is the same as `window.something = somethingelse`, and if that `something` is already a real property of the `Window` object, guess what happens =) (see answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working exactly as it's supposed to: the declarations ([but not assigned values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted)) for "age" and "occupation" are hoisted, so your console log shows them existing with value "undefined" (rather than throwing a `ReferenceError`), but `name` is special: you're not the one who declared it, even though your code makes it *look* like you are:

What's really going on is that the code you've written is scoped, and so when you say `var name = "tom"`, what you've actually written is `currentscope.name = "tom"`. In any kind of explicit scope (a function, a module, etc) this will behave the way you expected, but in *global* scope in a browser (or more precisely, "in any execution context in which your scope is `window`"), what this means is that your code actually executes as `window.name = "tom"`.

And so that's where things go wrong: `name` [already exists as a global property on the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Of course, this goes for any other value too, if you `var numbats = "cute";` in global scope, that's the same as `window.numbats = "cute";` so if you don't want to run into silent naming conflicts: don't declare things in global scope. Test this in a function (where `var name` will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `name`), or you can use modern JS and use `let` instead of a curly bracket block but of course then we're not using `var` anymore.

Fun little known fact: setting the global `name` to `"tom"` and then browsing the web for an hour in the same tab will, even an hour later, still have `window.name` be your value, unless someone else has changed it, which almost never happens. It's one of those hilarious ways in which multi-faceted tracking stays possible.

Comment: That explains a lot. Another thing to think about. Thanks for your help.